# What is the relationship between entropy of an image and edge detection in matlab

Tags: edge-detection, entropy, canny-operator, mse

I have found values of entropy, mean squared error and PSNR of edge detected images with respect to original images. I have different five edge detected images with different threshold and sigma values. To find which is the best combination of threshold and sigma, I need to find the best edge detected image.

Without visual inspection, Can I find it from the above values? I found from research paper that, if mean squared error image is low, detected edges are good. Can I use this concept? How does PSNR and Entropy affects?

Comment: "Without visual inspection" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection of the edge detection parameters is highly dependent on image quality, image content and the information that you want to extract form the image. So it is essentially application-dependent and subjective to a large extent.

No theory can help you. Probably the best you can do is to ajdust those parameters the way that pleases you on a subsample of your images, and feed this data together with the entropy, MSE and PSNR to a machine learning device.